# How to fix 'cannot assign to function call' in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

Im need to split a string in strings with 3 characters, then to change middle character to a char that not repeat in this string and to sort them.

```
def Ex3_Atestare(string):
    n = 1
    cuvant = list(string)
    for k in range(1,len(string)/3):
        cuvant(n) = '#'
        n = n + 2
    print(''.join(cuvant))
    chars = [string[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(string), 3)]
    for j in range(len(string)/3):
        chars[j].sort()
    return ''.join(chars)
```

Comment: `cuvant(n)` is interpreted as a function call.  To change it to list indexing, use `cuvant[n]`.

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line of code:

```
    cuvant(n) = '#'
```

because you are interpreting a list as a function. You need to do

```
    cuvant[n] = '#'
```

for indexing.